# Проблемы с сайтом

Tags: joomla, хостинг, домен

Перенес сайт на движке Joomla, все, как обычно уже делал много раз, через 15 минут все работало, сейчас уже прошло минут 40, если захожу со своего компа, то пишет страница не найдена, если заходить по ip, пишет зайдите через 15 минут, мы еще не настроили, но если захожу с компьютера друга по доменному имени, то просто пишет: "Could not connect" и все. Бывает пишет, что-то после двух точек, а тут не пишет ничего, в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, всем спасибо, нужно было просто еще в одном файле записать правильно хост.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблемы со стороны хостинга, напишите в тех. поддержку. А по ftp можно зайти?
И Вы точно Всё правильно прописали в конфиге? И дамп базы данных вы перенесли?

Comment: Да, если база не правильно писала бы, мол: "Could not connect:mysql" или типа того, да базу проверял уже не раз: в файле конфигурации все правильно, по фтп захожу спокойно, все папки, файлы на месте.

Comment: киньте ссылку на сайт, сложно что-то о джумле писать - это очень непредсказуемая штука=)

Comment: ucop.com.ua

Comment: я подожду часика два,а потом если не че не изменится позвоню в тех поддержку

Comment: Я даже не знаю, что такое, а  гуглили проблемку? Может, кто уже с этим сталкивался?

Comment: Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) я решил изменить в конфиге с mysql на mysqli теперь выписывает это...что это не знаю честно 

Comment: подсказать не берусь,но озвучьте плиз имя хостинга,так на всякий случай